# How to fill a hole between 2 circles quickly

Tags: mesh

If I had 2 circles placed on top of each other, like the cap and bottom of a cylinder, how would I fill in those walls without filling in the circles themselves?  (Basically, a cylinder without its top and bottom).  I'm not looking for a "just use a cylinder" in this case.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Select the two circles and bridge them using  <kbd>SPACE</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd>

[image: before]

[image: after before]